# Would flagging a "it's a typo" answer be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, flags

I was just about to flag an answer that just pointed out the user had misspelled "active" as "ative" as "Not an answer"

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Since it probably should be a comment/deleted/a close vote, but in some respect it *does* attempt to answer the question.

I'd imagine if I'd have flagged it it would have been denied or disputed, so am I right in thinking that the best action to take is to just move on?

Comment: Did you vote to close the question as a typo?

Comment: @RobertLongson - Yes, I did vote on the question. This is whether to flag an answer that was written by the FGITW

Comment: You can also come back to the question afterwards and vote to delete, if it's been closed long enough or has a sufficiently negative score

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, There is no flag for "answer that is reasonable and solves the question but should not have been provided". Generally dealing with such post via closing/removing (or letting Roomba remove) the question is better route, you may consider downvoting answer if you feel it is not useful.

- Not a SPAM. There is no promotion of any kind.
- Not rude at all
- Definitely not NAA/VLQ as it 100% looks like a readable answer to *a question* (probably even to that particular question).
- By itself it does not need moderator attention as the question will likely be closed as "typo" by users and there is no need for moderator intervention. You may look at other posts by the answer's author (just look, no votes) to see if *majority* of the posts are on clear off-topic questions - if that the case consider detailed moderator flag but see if commenting to the author first would be better.

Answer (score 4):

> [A]m I right in thinking that the best action to take is to just move on?

Yeah, as far as the answer is concerned. If you think it's a particularly bad answer, you can always down-vote it, but NAA flags is more for things like "I have this problem too," or, "Please help me!" You can also comment too if you need to.

As far as the question goes, you can always close it as a typo, if you think it can't be reproduced, or it won't be helpful to future readers. This kind of depends on how both the problem and its solution are written, though.